# Help evaluating a partial sum with factorials and binomial coefficients

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, factorial

I come from a CS background and had to contend with a problem similar to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736211/how-many-times-does-a-single-fair-die-have-to-be-rolled-for-a-number-to-repeat). Essentially, I want a general-case estimate on how many rolls I'd have to make to land on the same number twice with a (fair) $k$-sided die.

I got as far as this for an expected value:

$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{(k-1)!\cdot n^2}{(k-n)!\cdot k^n}$$

and managed to simplify it to this cute looking guy:

$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{\binom{k-1}{n-1}\cdot n!\cdot n}{k^n}$$

But here, i have no idea how to proceed, I'd do with a simple asymptotic approximation but I got nothing. Through computer simulation, I found this very close to $\sqrt{k}$ as far as $k=10^{10}$ but I can't really prove it, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Look up the birthday paradox problem and calculations related to it. Your empirical observation that it has something to do with $\sqrt{k}$ is right on the money.